# Text from listbox into array, text not making it into my array unless I click an item in the listbox first

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to capture the text all of the items in a listbox into an array. When I click the button to do this, it does correctly count and add the right number of items into the array but the text of the values in the listbox get carried over as nothing (""). This happens UNLESS I click on just a single item in the listbox first. Then all the items from the listbox make it into the array with their text values.

```
ReDim Components(lbUse.ListCount - 1) As String

For i = 0 To lbUse.ListCount - 1
    lbUse.Selected(i) = True
    Components(i) = lbUse.Text
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `Text` property. Use `List`. Try it like this instead:

```
ReDim Components(lbUse.ListCount - 1) As String

For i = 0 To lbUse.ListCount - 1
    Components(i) = lbUse.List(i)
Next
```

Also, depending on why you need this array, you might not, as the data you are accessing is already in a property array as you can see. You could just reference that instead of copying it to your own array.

The "other bug" you were experiencing was most likely coming from the use of setting the `ListIndex` using `Selection` unnecessarily.

Comment: Ahh thank you! I knew that way of "selecting" an item then getting the text was weird.